# Can I download all segments of a m3u8 file as one mp4 file using web ( no ffmpeg )

Tags: javascript, php, m3u8

Is it  possible to download all `m3u8` segments in one file using javascript or php

I search for this but couldn't find anything;

Comment: downloading all the segments is easy, but you will need to use a video conversion tool to reconstruct the mp4. this is normally done on the fly by javascript as the segments are downloaded

Comment: @andrew is it possible to save as ts without video conversion tool

Comment: Is it HLS you are asking about ? m3u8 can be used in a variety of situations. In the case of HLS, the container format is indeed TS (MPEG transport stream) which is different from MP4. The resulting file needs to be remuxed from TS into MP4.

Comment: without a convertor? no its not possible

Comment: what convertor should i use

Comment: probably ffmpeg, mp4Box might be a good one to look at for segmented video

Comment: Can i run ffmpeg in a php server

Comment: you can run ffmpeg on the same server that php is running on provided that your hosting company permits it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67475/discussion-between-elti-musa-and-andrew).

Comment: Did you finally find a way to solve this on the fly with javascript?

Answer (score 15):

**TL/DR:** 
I used the following code to download all the mpeg-ts chunk files from the m3u8 link, and then I convert each one of them into an .mp4 programmatically.

I ended up with many small .mp4 files which I could add into a vlc playlist and play, but I was not able to programmatically concatenate all those mp4 files into one mp4 file using javascript.

I've heard the last part of merging all those ts files into one mp4 file can be done with [mux.js](https://github.com/videojs/mux.js), but I haven't done it myself.

**Long version:**

What I ended up doing was I used [m3u8_to_mpegts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/m3u8_to_mpegts) to download each and every MPEG_TS file that the m3u8 file pointed to into a directory.

```
var TsFetcher = require('m3u8_to_mpegts');

TsFetcher({
    uri: "http://api.new.livestream.com/accounts/15210385/events/4353996/videos/113444715.m3u8",
       cwd: "destinationDirectory",
       preferLowQuality: true,
   }, 
   function(){
        console.log("Download of chunk files complete");
        convertTSFilesToMp4();
   }
);
```

Then I converted those .ts files into .mp4 files using [mpegts_to_mp4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mpegts_to_mp4)

```
var concat = require('concatenate-files');


// Read all files and run 
function getFiles(currentDirPath, callback) {
    var fs = require('fs'),
        path = require('path');
    fs.readdir(currentDirPath, function (err, files) {
        if (err) {
            throw new Error(err);
        }

        var fileIt = files.length;
        files.forEach(function (name) {
            fileIt--;
            // console.log(fileIt+" files remaining");
            var filePath = path.join(currentDirPath, name);
            var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);
            if (stat.isFile()) {
                callback(filePath, (fileIt==0));
            }
        });
    });
}




var mpegts_to_mp4 = require('mpegts_to_mp4');
var toConvertIt=0, doneConvertingIt = 0;

function convertTSFilesToMp4(){ 
    getFiles("destinationDirectory/bandwidth-198000", 
        function onFileDiscovered(filePath, noMoreFiles){   //onFileDiscovered runs for each file we discover in the destination directory
            var filenameParts = filePath.split("/"); // if on Windows execute .split("\\");, thanks Chayemor!
            var filename = filenameParts[2];
            if(filename.split(".")[1]=="ts"){   //if its a ts file
                console.log(filename);  

                mpegts_to_mp4(filePath, toConvertIt+'dest.mp4', function (err) {
                    // ... handle success/error ...
                    if(err){
                        console.log("Error: "+err);
                    }
                    doneConvertingIt++
                    console.log("Finished converting file "+toConvertIt);
                    if(doneConvertingIt==toConvertIt){
                        console.log("Done converting vids.");
                    }
                });
                toConvertIt++;
            }
        });
}
```

Caution: What to change in the given code if you wish to use it:

- The uri obviously
- the (cwd) location that you wish to save the ts files (mine was destinationDirectory)
- preferLowQuality set it to false if you prefer the highest quality it will find
- the location that you read your ts files from after you've downloaded them (mine was destinationDirectory/bandwidth-198000)

I hope this code helps someone in the future.
Special thanks to Tenacex for helping me out on this.

Comment: If executred on windows: var filenameParts = filePath.split("\\");

Comment: Many thanks for the awesome information. I have a query and wondering if you can help me resolve it. Query: I want to make my HLS videos available to user offline. Is it possible to store HLS video in users browser (in Indexed db etc) and then play directly from there. Is there any how I can make videos available offline?